# sed: Replacing a double quote in a quoted field within a delmited record

Tags: regex, unix, sed

Given an optionally quoted,  pipe delimited file with the following records:

`"foo"|"bar"|123|"9" Nails"|"2"
"blah"|"blah"|456|"Guns "N" Roses"|"7"
"brik"|"brak"|789|""BB" King"|"0"
"yin"|"yang"|789|"John "Cougar" Mellencamp"|"5"`

I want to replace any double quotes not next to a delimiter.

I used the following and it almost works.  With one exception.

`sed "s/\([^|]\)\"\([^|]\)/\1'\2/g" a.txt`

The output looks like this:

`"foo"|"bar"|123|"9' Nails"|"2"
"blah"|"blah"|456|"Guns 'N" Roses"|"7"
"brik"|"brak"|789|"'BB' King"|"0"
"yin"|"yang"|789|"John 'Cougar' Mellencamp"|"5"`

It doesn't catch the second set of quotes if they are separated by a single character as in Guns "N" Roses.  Does anyone know why that is and how it can be fixed?  In the mean time I'm just piping the output to a second regex to handle the special case.  I'd prefer to do this in one pass since some of the files can be largish.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you *should* be doing is using proper CSV and a proper CSV parser:  embedded double quotes in a field are doubled: `"blah"|"blah"|456|"Guns ""N"" Roses"|"7"`

Comment: Agreed.  Unfortunately I have no control over the generation of the source file.  I have to deal with it as it is.  BTW thanks for the perl solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use substitution twice in `sed`:

```
sed -r "s/([^|])\"([^|])/\1'\2/g; s/([^|])\"([^|])/\1'\2/g" file
"foo"|"bar"|123|"9' Nails"|"2"
"blah"|"blah"|456|"Guns 'N' Roses"|"7"
"brik"|"brak"|789|"'BB' King"|"0"
"yin"|"yang"|789|"John 'Cougar' Mellencamp"|"5"
```

Comment: I had to escape the parens but that got it.  It never occurred to me to run the same pattern twice.  I'll add that to my bag of tricks.  Thank you!

Comment: @RikBitter, did you use `sed -r`?

Answer (score 1):

sed kind of implements a "while" loop:

```
sed ':a; s/\([^|]\)"\([^|]\)/\1'\''\2/g; ta' file
```

The `t` command loops to the label `a` if the previous `s///` command replaced something. So that will repeat the replacement until no other matches are found.

Also, perl handles your case without looping, thanks to zero-width look-ahead:

```
perl -pe 's/[^|]\K"(?!\||$)/'\''/g'
```

But it doesn't handle consecutive double quotes, so the loop:

```
perl -pe 's//'\''/g while /[^|]\K"(?!\||$)/' file
```

You may like to use `\x27` instead of the awkward `'\''` method to insert a single quote in a single quoted string. Works with perl and GNU sed.